# SQL - Convert/Transpose Rows with Coded Text Values to Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, pivot-table, transpose

I'm looking for help transforming a table with data stored in rows, to data stored in tables.

Background...  I'm working with a table containing hospital admission data. Let's call the table "Inpatients".

The data is currently formatted as a table with 3 columns and *n* rows. The 3 columns hold the following data:

**"Patient_ID"** = *a unique patient/person identifier*.  Think of this as the patient's name;

**"Event_ID"** = *unique admission event identifier*.  Identifies unique episodes of care in hospital;

**"Diagnosis_Code"** = *[ICD-10 code](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2016/en)* used to record the reason why the patient is in hospital.

For an individual patient (Patient_ID) , *each* stay in hospital (Event_ID) is represented by **one or more** rows in the table, where one row is used for each diagnosis that is recorded for the given stay in hospital.

So any given stay in hospital may be captured by one row in the table (one recorded diagnosis) *or* multiple rows in the table (associated with multiple diagnoses).

An example of the current "Inpatients" table is given below...

```
-------------------------------------------
Patient_ID |  Event_ID   |  Diagnosis_Code
-------------------------------------------
Pers001    | HospStay001 |     C139
Pers001    | HospStay001 |     I245
Pers001    | HospStay001 |     D456
Pers001    | HospStay002 |     C139
Pers001    | HospStay002 |     J123
Pers555    | HospStay001 |     D312
Pers999    | HospStay001 |     C120
Pers999    | HospStay001 |     E101
```

**Here's what I really want to do**: I want to transform the data so that I have *one row only, for each hospital stay per patient*, so that the above table is formatted as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Patient_ID |  Event_ID   | Diagnosis_Code_1 | Diagnosis_Code_2 | Diagnosis_Code_3 | Diagnosis_Code_n
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pers001    | HospStay001 |       C139       |       I245       |       D456       |
Pers001    | HospStay002 |       C139       |       J123       |                  |
Pers555    | HospStay001 |       D312       |                  |                  |
Pers999    | HospStay001 |       C120       |       E101       |                  |
```

I suspect that the solution requires some dynamic sql... not one of my strengths I'm afraid.

Thanks!

Comment: Cross tabs might help: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8

Comment: Diagnosis_Code_1 | Diagnosis_Code_2 | Diagnosis_Code_3 | Diagnosis_Code_n  How to determine how many codes are available ? and Diagnosis code 1 has  c139,c139, d312,c120 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE  table #source (Patient_ID varchar(100), Event_ID varchar (100) ,Diagnosis_Code VARCHAR(100),Dig_Number INT)
insert into #source (Patient_ID, Event_ID,Diagnosis_Code,Dig_Number) values
('Pers001','HospStay001','I245',2),
('Pers001','HospStay001','D456',3),
('Pers001','HospStay002','C139',1),
('Pers001','HospStay002','J123',2),
('Pers555','HospStay001','D312',1),
('Pers999','HospStay001','C120',1),
('Pers999','HospStay001','E101',2),
('Pers001','HospStay001','C139',1)


--DROP TABLE tempdb..#source


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF
        (
          (
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dig_Number))
            FROM #source
            GROUP BY Dig_Number

            ORDER BY Dig_Number
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
          1,1,''
        );

SET @query = 'SELECT Patient_ID,Event_ID,' + @cols + ' 
              FROM
              (
                SELECT Patient_ID,Event_ID,Diagnosis_Code,dig_number
                FROM #source
             ) x
             PIVOT
             (
                MAX(Diagnosis_Code)
                FOR Dig_Number IN (' + @cols + ')
             ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

it will work if increase one more column which is dianosis number.

Comment: As this is an Access question, that won't work, since it's T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rajat Jaiswal, LeasMaps and Tim Biegeleisen for your contributions.  Much appreciated.

The suggestion to add an *additional column to the original table* to use as column headings in the transformed table was the key.  This turned out to be relatively easy to do (I did this in MS Excel).

So my original table was edited to look like this...

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Patient_ID |  Event_ID   | Diagnosis_Code | DiagCode_Counter |
--------------------------------------------------------------
Pers001    | HospStay001 |     C139       | Diagnosis_Code_1 |
Pers001    | HospStay001 |     I245       | Diagnosis_Code_2 |
Pers001    | HospStay001 |     D456       | Diagnosis_Code_3 |
Pers001    | HospStay002 |     C139       | Diagnosis_Code_1 |
Pers001    | HospStay002 |     J123       | Diagnosis_Code_2 |
Pers555    | HospStay001 |     D312       | Diagnosis_Code_1 |
Pers999    | HospStay001 |     C120       | Diagnosis_Code_1 |
Pers999    | HospStay001 |     E101       | Diagnosis_Code_2 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

In he newly added **"DiagCode_Counter"** field, the numeric suffix increments by 1, each time a new **Diagnosis_Code** value is recorded against a unique **"Event_ID"**.

I was then able to create a *Crosstab* query in MS Access, using the **"Patient_ID"** and **"Event_ID"** fields as *ROW* headings; the"DiagCode_Counter" field for *COLUMN* headings; and the **"Diagnosis_Code"** entries as *VALUES*.

Answer (score 0):

Rajat is correct - you need some sort of column to use to create diagnosis_column_1, dignosis_column_2....etc

To do this in ms-access I would:
1. Create a Dummy Column to count the Diagnosis Columns
2. Use VBA to populate it (faster for large databases) as follows

```
Sub Update_Diagnosis_Code_ID()

Dim db As DAO.Database
'Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim TmpRecord As String

Dim dummyId As Integer
Dim patientID As String
Dim eventID As String

Dim lastDummyId As Integer
Dim lastpatientID As String
Dim lasteventID As String

Dim i As Integer

pstrSQL = "SELECT Inpat.Dummy_id, Inpat.Patient_id, Inpat.Event_ID, Inpat.Diagnosis_Code FROM Inpat ORDER BY Inpat.Patient_id, Inpat.Event_ID;"
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(pstrSQL)

dummyId = 0


With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
    'first record
      .MoveFirst

        patientID = rs.Fields(1) '
        eventID = rs.Fields(2) '
        .Edit
        rs.Fields(0) = dummyId + 1
        .Update
        .MoveNext

        Do While Not .EOF
          'store the values from the last record
          lastpatientID = patientID
          lasteventID = eventID

          'get the new values

          patientID = rs.Fields(1) '
          eventID = rs.Fields(2) '

          'new patient or new hospital stay
          If patientID <> lastpatientID Or eventID <> lasteventID Then
            dummyId = 0 'reset back to 1
          Else
            dummyId = dummyId + 1
          End If

          .Edit
          rs.Fields(0) = dummyId + 1
          .Update
          .MoveNext

        Loop
      End If
    End With

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

MsgBox "Finished", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Then if use a crosstab to display the data:

```
TRANSFORM First(Inpat.[Diagnosis_Code]) AS FirstOfDiagnosis_Code
SELECT Inpat.[Patient_id], Inpat.[Event_ID], Count(Inpat.[Diagnosis_Code]) 
AS [Total Of Diagnosis_Code]
FROM Inpat
GROUP BY Inpat.[Patient_id], Inpat.[Event_ID]
PIVOT Inpat.[Dummy_id];
```